# Charts on the torus as a quotient of $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

In

[Finding coordinate charts from a torus (square with sides identified) to $\mathbb R^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219999/305983)

the answer says we can put charts on the torus by open balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ on the boundary of the unit square and sending a point to it's image under the quotient map. Won't $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ not be in the image of any chart this way? If we make the radius larger, aren't these maps not injective?

Comment: Skimming quickly through the proof in the linked answer: it seems you are right - but this is easy to fix, add another open ball with the centre in $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$. Actually, it seems to me that you can get away with just four open balls: centres in $(0,0)$, $(0,1/2)$, $(1/2,0)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$, all with radius $1/2$.

Comment: @user8734617 Thanks! That's what I thought. In a textbook I was looking at (Burns and Gidea) they cover the lattice points of the square with balls of radius $r \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1)$. They claim that the maps are then injective. Just for my own sanity, that's false right? Since $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ have the same image in the quotient?

Comment: I don't have access to the book, so cannot judge; from the information you've provided, it looks like you are right.

Comment: @user8734617 Thank you. If you post an answer I will accept (if you want the points.) If not, I really appreciate it!